# Implementing phpsysinfo into zf2

Tags: zend-framework2

does anybody know how to implement [phpsysinfo](https://packagist.org/packages/phpsysinfo/) into a ZF2 project?
I need a brief overview what is hapening on the server without having to connect via ssh to the server. There are a lot of monitoring software I know, but this will do the job for me. Thx for any reply...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phpSysInfo is a standalone software, which is not intended to be integrated into another project (e.g. ZF2)

You can probably reuse some classed from the source code, if you build a ZF2 module